# My Android Widget stop refreshing the view

Tags: android, animation, view, android-widget, invalidation

I wrote an Android clock widget. 
The widget includes gif animations.

My widget has its owns service that maintain its views. and threads that plays the animations.

For unclear reason, at some point in time after the widget starts, it stop playing the animations, as if the view freez. At first I thought the underlying service broke, or one of the threads were in deadlock.

What I found was that everything runs perfectly, only the view doesn't change.

If this was a normal application view, I would have thought I should call invalidate() on the view - but the RemoteViews doesn't have such call.

Anyone has experience with similar problem?

Answer (score -1):

I think you might call the invalidate() from non-UI thread. The method invalidate() need to be called in UI thread only. If it is the case, use postInvalidate() rather than invalidate().

Refer the following documentation for more info,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29

Comment: postInvalidate() you can only send to a view within a window (as far as I know). a Widget view is not accessible this way, only through RemoteView. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ok. For remote views we need to make use of broadcast receiver.. Broadcast the values you need and receive the values by onReceive() method then call onUpdate() in onReceive() itself. I think this will work fine.. Please refer < vogella.de/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html#updates>